# HTML Input Tabbing beyond visible area modifies what?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, styles

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/senica/f2p96/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
    <div><input type="text" /></div>
</div>

#container{
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow:hidden;                    
}
```

Given the above example, if I click in the first box and begin pushing tab, the browser will auto scroll "something" to keep the focused element in view.

What is it that is being modified in order for this to happen? It is not the position of anything.

I have looked at all the computed styles in Chrome develper tools and nothing changes.

I have not begun exploring properties only accessible to javascript yet. I figured I would ask and see if anyone else knew.

### Clarification

To clarify any confusion: I want to know how far the browser has moved whatever it is that it is moving in order to keep the focused input element in view.

### Answer?

So the input's parent element's scrollTop does seem to change. Perhaps this is what I'm looking for.

### Should be a separate question

Can you tell the browser which element to scroll or will it always be the form elements direct parent?

Comment: Are you talking about `tabindex`? That is what controls what gets focus first.  Positive tabindex means that the element gets priority first with `1` being the highest priority.  Value of 0 means that it has regular tab flow and negative means the element should not get focus from tab.

Comment: @zero298, no. I'm talking about the positioning. What is it that moves and what property is it that moves. How can I determine how far the browser has scrolled *something* from someone tabbing to a new field.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you mean.  The focus is changing do to the tab key being pressed.  A roundabout way of figuring out how for you've moved after pressing tab to change focus, would be to bind to the tab `keydown` event, record the absolute position of the the element you are on, and bind to the `keypress` event and measure the distance of the newly focused element.  The focus change *should* occur between the keydown and keypress.  As to the "separate question", what gets focused is still dictated by `tabindex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [`scrollTop` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop).  When you scroll the "page", browsers differ in which element's `scrollTop` property gets updated.  In Chrome and IE, it's `document.documentElement`, in FireFox it's `document.body`.  (Personally, `document.body` makes the most sense to me, but whatever...)  The cross-browser way of determining the page's scroll position is:

```
var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

But, sometimes it's not the page that scrolls.  When you have an element with `overflow:auto`  whose content doesn't fit (it overflows), you will get scroll bars on that element.  In that case, you can read the `scrollTop` property of that element.

In fact, if the `overflow` is anything other than `visible`, that element is scrollable - it's just a bit trickier to do it.  You can scroll such elements by selecting the text, or, as you discovered, by using the keyboard to give focus to hidden elements.  The `scrollTop` property will give you the scroll position of that element too.

Scroll position is not configurable via CSS.  You can, however, modify it with script.

Regarding your "separate" question, the element that scrolls will be the closest ancestor element  whose content has overflown its boundaries.  You could override that behavior with JavaScript.

It get's more interesting when you have nested scrollable elements.  Look what happens to your jsFiddle when you mix in some nested scrollable containers: [jsfiddle.net/f2p96/3](http://jsfiddle.net/f2p96/3/)

Comment: Heh, for sure. We are doing our own touchscrolling for our app as we had quite a few issues with Chromes implementation. This one really made me scratch my head as I could not figure out what was being modified. The silly thing was, that occasionally someone would see the screen 'jump' and a ticket would be opened but no one could ever duplicate consistently. I finally figured out the source of the issue when doing a browser ctrl+F to find something...same sort of thing happens.